# Group by solution

Tags: sql

I've got a query that I'm trying to run and not sure how to get around the not a group by issue. I need to calculate the total number of orders for a customer, but only show the customers who have ordered in March.

```
SELECT customer#, firstname || ', ' || lastname "Customer Name", orderdate, 
COUNT(order#)
FROM orders JOIN customers
USING (customer#)
WHERE orderdate LIKE '%MAR%'
GROUP BY customer#;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tag your DBMS ?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: please edit your question with some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here might be to just add the first and last customer name to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    customer#,
    firstname || ', ' || lastname "Customer Name",
    COUNT(order#) AS cnt
FROM orders
JOIN customers
USING (customer#)
WHERE orderdate LIKE '%MAR%'
GROUP BY
    customer#,
    firstname || ', ' || lastname
```

It appears that you are using a natural join, which IMHO makes it hard to see what is actually happening during the join itself.  You might want to switch to use explicit join syntax here.

Also note that strictly speaking the above query is not ANSI compliant because it contains a function of columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.  This is easy to remedy; we can just use a subquery first to concatenate the first and last names, and then aggregate on that.